# SQL Server : find rows that specific column value not change in last 24 hour

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my sample table

[image]

I want get last row of BB because money column of BB not changed in last 24 hour ...

What is the right query for this in SQL Server ?

Comment: what sql server version?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza : SQL SERVER EXPRESS 2008

Comment: only for money column or all columns?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza : only money if is duplicate

Comment: According to your data, none of them change within 24 hours.   So why only the last row of BB?

Comment: @TabAlleman time have fake value i mean only money value in important

Comment: Ok, then why wouldn't you want the last TWO rows for BB, since both have money values that don't change from the previous row?

Comment: I think this comment in my answer is important --- my table contain ATM status and save about 500 ATMs status in every 30 min ... i want find which ATM don't pay any money to customer in last 24 hour

Comment: @abbas I think you need remake the question. please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example: Not include column `printer` if that isnt necesary for your query. Write the sample table: We cant do query over images and transcript take time. Or try to create a **http://sqlfiddle.com/** with sample data. Also you say `Date` field is fake but at least create something making sense. You should use `datetime` and contain some rows matching / no matching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Early.*
FROM sampleTable Early
JOIN sampleTable Older
  ON Early.Name = Older.Name
 AND Early.Money = Older.Money
 AND DATEDIFF ( day , Older.time, Early.time) >= 1
```

Take note if only one record, there is nothing to compare and wont appear on the query.

Comment: how filter rows for search for speed up executing ? my table is very large and about 1000000 rows in it ? for example only search in last one week

Comment: Create index for Name and Money. Also you should have to think what you need or why you need it. That way maybe we can optimize something. Right now only the index may help.

Comment: my table contain ATM status and save about 500 ATMs status in every 30 min ...
i want find which ATM don't pay any money to customer in last 24 hour

Answer (score -1):

You have to make a "after update" trigger and in the trigger insert the records to temp_table including a update datetime column. This will allow to track each update for each row.
This is MySQL trigger example
**MySQL**

```
create trigger ai_table_trigger for each row
begin
  insert into temp_table(record_id,update_datetime)values(old.id,now());
end
```

Comment: doesnt make any sense